# What is the JavaScript regex to match config.*.json?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match `config.json` and `config.staging.json` and `config.anything.json`

So far I have `configFile.match /config\.(.*)\.json/i`

Comment: consider that when `.*` matches nothing the rest of the pattern is `config..json`.

Comment: If it were me, I'd use two separate regexes: `/^config\./i.test(configFile) && /\.json$/i.test(configFile)`. Easy code to read, easy code to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're requiring that there be two dots, but in `config.json`, there's only one. You could use a non-capturing group for the optional second bit:

```
/config(?:\.(.+))?\.json/i
```

I assume you wanted that capture group there, to capture `staging` or `anything`.

You might also want anchors, so it doesn't match `fooconfig.jsonasdlfja`:

```
/^config(?:\.(.+))?\.json$/i
```

Examples:

```js
var rex = /^config(?:\.(.+))?\.json$/i;
var tests = {
  "config.json": [true, undefined],
  "config.staging.json": [true, "staging"],
  "config.anything.json": [true, "anything"],
  "CONFIG.JSON": [true, undefined],
  "cOnFiG.StAgInG.JsOn": [true, "StAgInG"],
  "fooconfig.json": null,
  "config.jsonfoo": null,
  "configjson": null
};
Object.keys(tests).forEach(function(str) {
  var result = describe(str.match(rex)),
      expect = describe(tests[str]);
  snippet.log("Testing: " + str);
  snippet.log("Result : " + result);
  snippet.log("Expect : " + expect);
  if (result == expect) {
    snippet.log("Correct");
  } else {
    snippet.log("**ERROR**");
  }
  snippet.log("--");
});

function describe(r) {
  if (r) {
    if (r[1]) {
      return "Match, captured '" + r[1] + "'";
    }
    return "Match, no capture";
  }
  return "No match";
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not work for `config..json` and `config.jsonot` strings

Answer (score 0):

Your **config<-somthing->.json** regex is

```
/\bconfig(\.[\w]+)*\.json\b/gi

where:
\b word boundry
\. dot character
[\w] followed by any word character
()* matches this part zero or more times
/gi global case ignored search
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bN7sE0/7) for examples and results